# How to remove header footer only for the first page - mpdf

Tags: mpdf

Below two functions in the Mpdf adding the header and footer in all the pages.

SetHTMLHeader() 
SetHTMLFooter()

But, anyone please help me to remove the header and footer from the first page of the pdf?

Comment: Was the answer of @Christer working ? Please accept it to let know others after you that it is a good answer. If now please leave a comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mPDF disable page number, header and footer on first page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019643/mpdf-disable-page-number-header-and-footer-on-first-page)

Answer (score 1):

mPDF has an option on this called "show-this-page" : 
- Setting this to `0` would, i guess, not show it on the first page.

Have a look at the documentation: 
http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=253

Comment: this one is not correct - setting to 0 or 1 just tells the footer so show/hide at the current position in the doc, it has nothing to to specitfically with the 1st page etc.. check the doc here: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=180

Comment: I never said it was specific to the first page either. But its something that would work. As far as i can see, there isnt a pre defined option for disabling the footer on the first page. So therefore you just have to find a workaround like this :)

Comment: it would be OK if it would work. But it doesn't. At least for me it does not.

Comment: Aha - I just remember that i used it when printing out PDFs that would be 100 pages, and every second page would need to hide the footer.